# On the asymptotic joint distribution of two weighted Bernoulli sums

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, normal-distribution

Let $\theta_i$ be a Bernoulli random variable of success probability $p$.

Given two fixed sets $A = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_N\}$ and $B = \{b_1, b_2, ..., b_N\}$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are constants.

For any realisations $Z = \{\theta_1, \theta_2,..., \theta_N\}$, wee define two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that:

\begin{equation}
X = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i \theta_i
\end{equation}

and,

\begin{equation}
Y = \sum_{i=1}^{N} b_i \theta_i
\end{equation}

Clearly, $X$ and $Y$ are correlated and in the large limit of $N$ each follows a normal distribution with means and variances depending on the fixed sets $A$ and $B$.

**What is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ ?**

I know that if two variables, say  $U$ and $V$, are jointly gaussian, then any linear combination $W = \alpha U + \beta V$ follows a gaussian distribution BUT the converse need not to be true.

However, what is funny with this question is that $X$ and $Y$ is marginally gaussian in the limit of large enough $N$ and the same holds for all linear combinations of the two. If I were to perform a simulation and draw the heatmap the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$, I would get some shape that is not symmetrical with respect to the mean values of $X$ and $Y$ (see figure below where the red dotted lines represents the means of $X$ and $Y$)

[image]

Hence, the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ cannot be gaussian.

Any references or answer to this question would be gladly appreciated.

*We will avoid the trivial case where $A$ and $B$ are identical*

**Note: This has been cross-posted on "cross-validated"**